# Stirling numbers and left right minima

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

How does one prove that the # of n- element permutations with k left-right minima is given by the 1st kind stirling number?

I understand one should consider sigma(1)=n and sigma(1)=/=n, but I am totally lost on the process
A left-right minimum of a permutation σ is an index σ(j) such that σ(j) < σ(i) for all i < j

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Could you please remind us what a "left-right minimum" is?

Comment: Yep, added the information in :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of a permutation as a list of the numbers $1,\ldots,n$ in some order.
One gets such a permutation by "inserting" $n$ somewhere in a permutation
of $1,\ldots,n-1$. If one inserts it at the beginning one gains one
left-right minimum. If one inserts it elsewhere the number of left-right
minima remains the same.

So to get an $n$-permutation with $k$ left-right minima, either one prefixes
an $(n-1)$-permutation with $k-1$ minima with an $n$, or else inserts
an $n$ into an $(n-1)$-permutation with $k$ minima in one of the $n-1$
possible locations that's not at the front.

This gives the Stirling recurrence.